# this.NavigationController is null (xamarin ios stoaryboard)

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

when I'm moving from one story board to another storyboard via click on signIn button, this.NavigationController is showing null. so I'm not able to PushViewController.

I've one stoaryboard with two views and that two views have separate UIViewControllers.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must explicitly create a UINavigationController and place your initial view controller inside of it.  Doing this will automatically set the NavigationController property of any view controller contained within that Navigation controller.

```
// create the view controller for your initial view - using storyboard, code, etc
var first = new UIViewController(...); 

// wrap your VC inside a Nav controller
var nav = new UINavigationController(first);
```

Comment: usually I would put it in my AppDelegate when I assign my root view controller, but it depends on your app's architecture

Comment: This will work and is standard. Another way you can do it is by adding a Navigation Controller to the first Storyboard, remove the RootViewController that comes with the NavigationController, and Draw a new Segue from Navigation Controller to the SignInController and set action as Root.

Comment: I've done it that way, Sreeraj, in the designer and I'm still getting a null NavigationController. I can't assign to it either as it's only got a get.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Jason's answer. By default the RootViewcontroller is the initial view controller.
What I did was to override the that initial view controller with the a navigation view controller:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    public override UIWindow Window
    {
        get;
        set;
    } 

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        Window.RootViewController = new UINavigationController(Window.RootViewController);
        return true;
    }
```

This is the line I added:

```
Window.RootViewController = new UINavigationController(Window.RootViewController);
```

Window.RootViewController: is the ViewController, e.g MainViewController
and I'm overriding this initial controller, that's set by default, with the navigation controller.
This worked perfectly for me.